# In one UIViewController, how can I judge it is to to next UIViewController, or return to last UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

For iOS UIViewController ,  when go to next UIViewController, or return to last UIViewController,  the `viewDidDisappear` and `viewWillDisappear` Life Cycle  will all appear, so how can I judge  it is to to next `UIViewController`, or return to last UIViewController ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `isMovingToParentViewController` and `isMovingFromParentViewController` methods of `UIViewController` to determine if a view controller is appearing or disappearing as a result of a push or a pop.

More explanation can be found in [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH2-SW12).